# Laravel 5.4 Rare Response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am facing problems with Laravel.

- i use AJAX to perform a product save, The first save indicates success.

  - `{status: "SUCCESS"}`
- The second one also save well but ajax goes to .fail method and this is the full response.

  - `1010910110{status: "SUCCESS"}`

As you can see there is a number "1010910110" and i do not know where that number come from.

controller response:

```
return response()->json(['status' => 'SUCCESS']);
```

Comment: solved i am very sorry was my bad please erase this post hahaha

Comment: I think you left some kind of text somewhere on your code. Anyways, if you solve your questions, write a quick info on how did you solved it, it can help people in future.